# C# how to close a ftp connection

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I have an SSIS script task that I want want to move a file on a ftp to another folder but I want to make sure I close the connection after if it is open still.

```
        //Move the File to Archive Folder
        FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(FTPFileFullPath);
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename;
        ftpRequest.RenameTo = ArchFilePath;
        FtpWebResponse ftpResp = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();

        ftpRequest.KeepAlive = false; // close connection... not sure
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

I have put .KeepAlive = false, is this the correct method, any tips most welcome.

Comment: Check the FtpWebRequest and [FtpWebResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebresponse?view=netframework-4.7.2) documentation. The `KeepAlive` property does not do what you think

Comment: Have you seen this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050381/how-to-properly-disconnect-from-ftp-server-with-ftpwebrequest)?

Comment: So if I have understood correctly from the link
ftpRequest.KeepAlive = false; // this drops the object not the connection?
ftpWebResponse.Close(); // this closes the connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FtpWebResponse` implements `IDisposable` so you should place it in a `using` block to ensure the streams are closed.

Comment: Also setting the `FtpWebRequest.KeepAlive` property to false before calling the `GetResponse()` could be useful